# Concatenating strings += vs another method

Tags: java, string

What is another way to concatenate besides `+=`?

```js
String s = "";
       s += "variable1 " + variable2 + " " + variable3 + "-" + variable4 + "(" + variable5):;
```

my exmample assuming variables have been assigned is above what is another way besides `+=`

Comment: [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) maybe ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [concate method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_concat.htm):

```
a.concat(b)
```

or you can use the append method like this:

```
new StringBuilder().append("firstString").append("secondString").toString()
```

Comment: and how would I implement that with say example above?

Comment: How woule I implement it with the example I gave

Answer (score 0):

If you choose `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder` then you can use `append()` method like this -

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Samp");
sb.append("le String");
```

Comment: how would I implement that with say the example I gave

Answer (score 0):

[StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Or:

```
String s1;

String s2;


String concatedStr = s1.concat(s2);
```

StringBuilder is preferred performance-wise.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach than StringBuilder.
If you have a collection (or just an array) you can use the [Join](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) method provided by Apache StringUtils
You can even add separators.

Answer (score 0):

Method you mentioned, using operator +, can be slow, and require more memory. Every time you use +, it creates another target string literal, and copies the 2 source string literals. It is inefficient.
The solution is to use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) or [StringBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html).
The difference between the two is that StringBuffer is thread-safe, which makes StringBuilder faster.